# How to create File manager in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm new to flash. I want to create File Manager in Flash. How to start with it? I want to embed that file manager on web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create (local system) file manager for Flash player because it would violate lots of security standards. With Flash you can only create Adobe AIR application that you have to install on your local computer (as any other software).